# Passing a struct as a command-line argument to a process using execl() function call in C

Tags: command-line, struct, arguments

I am trying to add SSL functionality to my existing TCP echo client-server application.

Earlier in my simple server, I was spawning a new child for every incoming client connection. To this child, I was passing the conn-fd (char*) as a command-line argument. (shown below)

```
execl("./simple_server_instance", conn_fd, NULL);
```

Now, for my secure server, I need to pass a CYASSL object (a structure in effect) instead of the conn_fd. (shown below)

```
ssl = CyaSSL_new(ctx);
CyaSSL_set_fd(ssl, connfd);
```

Here 'ssl' is the object that needs to be passed to the child process. I tried the following ways to achieve it, but unsuccessful. Is there a simple alternative, or should i go the serialization way?

1. Typecasting the ssl object to char*
2. Creating a buffer and doing a memcpy of the entire structure. (shown below)

> ```
> unsigned char sslobjbuf[sizeof(ssl)];
> memcpy(&sslobjbuf, ssl, sizeof(ssl));
> execl("./secure_server_instance", "hello", "25", sslobjbuf, NULL );
> ```

sdsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `execl()` a process, you completely replace the running process with the exec'ed process.  The `exec` family of functions expect a sequence of null terminated strings which will become available as `arvg[]` in the spawned application.  You can't just pass arbitrary objects via this interface.

When you probably want to use instead is the `fork` system call which gives you a new child process which shares its code/data with the parent.  The code for `./simple_server_instance` would be merged with the main server code.  You can do your `ssl = CyaSSL_new(ctx);` call in the parent process to obtain the object you require, then `fork`.  The parent can then continue to serve new requests while the child runs the the `ssl` object.

Something like this flow of control may work:

```
while (1) {
    wait_connection();
    pid_t child_pid = -1;
    ssl = CyaSSL_new(ctx);
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {
        /* We're now running the child process which also has access to ssl.
         * Run simple_server_instance handler code
         */
    }
    else {
        /* Code running in parent.  Do housekeeping, save child_pid if necessary.
         * clean up ssl, object, get ready for next connection, handle finished
         * child processes.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Philips. What you have suggested is something i am doing already. Within the child, I am calling exec() system call to invoke a new binary. This new process is the one to which, I need to pass the ssl object.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the exec() occurs in parent or child - wherever it is called, the entire process will be replaced with the exec'ed binary.  Compile the sources for the server and simple_server_instance into the one binary.  The usual approach for fork and exec is to open a set of pipes for communication between parent and child.  The child inherits the pipe handles from the parent which it can then use to communicate.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec